# How to move to another page and then to a certain section of the page using a Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 files:

- mainPage.html
- starter.html
- Landing.js

When I click on the div in *starter.html* I want to move to *mainPage.html* and then to the Menu section of this page

**starter.html code:**

```
<li> <div onclick="onBackToMenu()">Back to menu</div></li>
```

**landing.js code:**

```
function onBackToMenu() {
   window.location.href = "../mainPage.html";

   document.getElementById("Menu").scrollIntoView();

}
```

**mainPage.html: (partial code)**

```
<!--    Menu section -->
    <span class="anchor-offset" id="Menu"></span>
    <div class ="section" >
        
        <div class ="sectionHeadings">
            <h1>Menu/Products</h1>
            <div class="menu">
                
                <div class="starter" onclick="location.href='pages/starter.html';">
                    <h3 class="menu-heading starter-heading">Starters</h3>
                </div>
```

When I click on the div then it does take me to mainPage.html, but it doesnt want to take me to the Menu section with id of Menu.

Please help

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an id on that section already ==>  `<span class="anchor-offset" id="Menu"></span>` pass the id at the end of your href like this:  `window.location.href = "../mainPage.html#Menu";` this will a direct you to that section when the new page loads.

```js
function onBackToMenu() {
   window.location.href = "../mainPage.html#Menu";

   document.getElementById("Menu").scrollIntoView();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No javascript is necessary. It's better practice and better for accessibility to use an [anchor element (`<a>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) with an `href` element to create a hyperlink to the new page with a [fragment identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#fragment) for the section you want to scroll to.

In your case, just change the list item in **starter.html** to:

```html
<li><a href="../mainPage.html#Menu">Back to menu</a></li>
```

This will navigate a user to the menu section of the new page.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that you could set a tag after the page. That is so easy!